# Is there any way to block all unencrypted connections?

Tags: networking, osx-lion, debian, encryption

I'm in the United States and I really don't think what I do is any of my ISP's business. No, I'm not doing anything illegal, I would just rather they not be watching everything.

I tried TOR a few years ago, but as I recall, it was ridiculously slow, and I got tired of it quickly…it might work as a fallback, though, if a server doesn't accept secure connections.

I have multiple computers, one running OS X Lion, the others running Debian squeeze. Ideally, the solution would work for all of them, let me set exceptions for specific domains, and prompt me once per program per domain when a program tries to establish an insecure connection. I realize that might not be possible, though, so whatever you have is welcome :)

Comment: *I tried TOR a few years ago, but as I recall, it was ridiculously slow, and I got tired of it quickly* -- A few years ago? That's like a hundred in computer years.

Comment: I think the only practical way to do this is to use a firewall and block all outgoing traffic, and then make special rules that let what you deem *allowed traffic* through (https, ssh).

Comment: If you have access to another machine (preferably a server) in another place, you might want to take a look at [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn).

Comment: Or purchase a subscription to a service like ipredator or hidemyass VPN

Comment: @Izzy I have a VPS that might work for this. How would I know my host isn't sniffing packets, though? Is there a list somewhere of ISPs and hosts that don't?

Comment: @Nifle Heh, okay. I might try it again, but frankly I'd rather not…

Comment: @BlacklightShining Don't know. I know my ISP personally :)

Comment: @Nifle I think I might actually do that. Thanks! :)